# downloading mails and save mail as .eml format, using microsoft graphclient service in c#

Tags: c#

Please help me to download emails and save mail as .eml format, using Microsoft graph client service(outlook) in c#.
I have message Id, but I didn't find any code for saving emails as eml format in the local path. using c# code

```
   GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = await GetGraphApiClient(authResult.AccessToken.ToString());
   var messages = await graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request()
                                .OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC").Top(int.MaxValue)
                                .GetAsync();
```

Please share some sample code or reference links to download mails.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was just made available [in September 2019](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/mime-format-support-for-outlook-mail-and-attachments-translate-item-id-apis-are-now-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1-0/).

As you can see from the documentation, the SDK [is usually behind the API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/11/07/how-to-use-the-net-microsoft-graph-sdk-to-get-users-and-get-next-page-of-results/), so unfortunately you can't yet use the `GetGraphApiClient` class.

> The Microsoft Graph SDK isn't updated as frequently as the Microsoft Graph API, which makes the Microsoft Graph SDK lag behind a bit. The most effective way to keep up with the Microsoft Graph API is to utilize the HTTPClient, and then parse the response body accordingly. If you would like to utilize the data structures and requests predefined in the Microsoft Graph SDK that is fine, however know that the SDK will not always be up to date with the Microsoft Graph API.

This means that you can use the first link functionality [using the 4th example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/4aade2547798441eab5188a7a2436bc1/$value`

The trick is the `$value` at the end of the url. Then you get the body in the mime format and you can save as it as you like.

Comment: var message1 = await graphServiceClient.Me.Messages[msg.Id]
    .Request()
    .Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"")
    .Select(e => new {
        e.Subject,
        e.Body,
        e.BodyPreview,
        e.UniqueBody
    })
    .GetAsync();                                                                                              using using above code hoe  to save mail as .eml format in local drive

Comment: var result = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/"+ msg.Id+ "/$value");   Im using token based authentication to access  mailbox. using above code show error "unauthorized". using only application id is possible to download mail in local path?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample for java. You can search for making custom request in c#.

```
Object stream = graphClient.customRequest( "/users/ {id} /messages/ {id}/ $value") .buildRequest().get();
```